# Identifying the regular script-style font on the shirt of the Normal Cell from "Cells at Work"

Tags: font-identification, japanese

What is the font used for the "細胞" on the Normal Cell's shirt from "Cells at Work"?

It's recognizably some sort of regular script-styled font, probably one meant for Japanese because of the open "胞". In a font meant for Chinese, that is closed off.

A search in [Fontworks](https://en.fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/) suggests it could be one of:

- Utrillo
- <s>Greco</s> Not this one, because the left radical of "細" is the incorrect variant.
- New Greco
- New Greco (N Type)

Which is it?

[image: cells at work normal cell]

Comment: Are you sure it's a font?  Not everything is a font. Since it's an illustration it's entirely possible that the characters were drawn by hand. When looking for an actual font, you might just have to go with one which is close.  Have you tried likefont.com? It can sometimes automatically detect CJK fonts.

Comment: @BillyKerr likefont.com actually was the first thing I tried, but every attempt I made gave a "抱歉，系统并未通过机器识别找到符合的字体。"  ("Sorry, the system did not find a matching font through machine recognition."). For now I'm using KaiTi to replicate it, since it's the only regular script font I have on my system, but it has the Chinese character forms rather than the Japanese ones.